# Fetching records from database and displaying them as different values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, offset

I've been practising php & mysql and at the moment I'm creating a simple database manager. Everything works fine except for this piece of code: http://snipt.org/vCW0

What this code is supposed to do is to get all the results from the database and display them, except while showing the position and the team name it should change position and team name values (which I insert into the database using abbreviations, e.g. 'qb' instead of 'Quarterback' to save the space) into their full equivalents (so 'gba' should display as 'Green Bay Packers', etc.) (and at the end a form for adding new entries). It actually displays them correctly but when I add a new player to the database, I get the following error:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'qb' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 97

Warning: Illegal string offset 'rb' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 98

Warning: Illegal string offset 'fb' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 99

Warning: Illegal string offset 'te' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 100

Warning: Illegal string offset 'wr' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 101

Warning: Illegal string offset 'ol' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 102

Warning: Illegal string offset 'dt' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 103

Warning: Illegal string offset 'de' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 104

Warning: Illegal string offset 'mlb' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 105

Warning: Illegal string offset 'olb' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 106

Warning: Illegal string offset 'cb' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 107

Warning: Illegal string offset 's' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 108

Warning: Illegal string offset 'ret' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 109

Warning: Illegal string offset 'k' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 110

Warning: Illegal string offset 'p' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 111

Warning: Illegal string offset 'ari' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 116

Warning: Illegal string offset 'atl' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 117

Warning: Illegal string offset 'bal' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 118

Warning: Illegal string offset 'buf' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 119

Warning: Illegal string offset 'car' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 120

Warning: Illegal string offset 'chi' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 121

Warning: Illegal string offset 'cin' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 122

Warning: Illegal string offset 'cle' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 123

Warning: Illegal string offset 'dal' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 124

Warning: Illegal string offset 'den' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 125

Warning: Illegal string offset 'det' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 126

Warning: Illegal string offset 'gba' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 127

Warning: Illegal string offset 'hou' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 128

Warning: Illegal string offset 'ind' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 129

Warning: Illegal string offset 'jax' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 130

Warning: Illegal string offset 'kan' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 131

Warning: Illegal string offset 'mia' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 132

Warning: Illegal string offset 'min' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 133

Warning: Illegal string offset 'nen' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 134

Warning: Illegal string offset 'nor' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 135

Warning: Illegal string offset 'nyg' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 136

Warning: Illegal string offset 'nyj' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 137

Warning: Illegal string offset 'oak' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 138

Warning: Illegal string offset 'phi' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 139

Warning: Illegal string offset 'pit' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 140

Warning: Illegal string offset 'sdg' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 141

Warning: Illegal string offset 'sfr' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 142

Warning: Illegal string offset 'sea' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 143

Warning: Illegal string offset 'stl' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 144

Warning: Illegal string offset 'tam' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 145

Warning: Illegal string offset 'ten' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 146

Warning: Illegal string offset 'was' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 147

Warning: Illegal string offset 'gba' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 153

Warning: Illegal string offset 'qb' in C:\web\project2\ranking_nfl.php on line 154
```

However, despite the error the record is added to the database and shown on the page. Deleting records doesn't show any errors.

Here is the full code: http://snipt.org/vCV8

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `$position` and `$team` to mean both the posted values from the form, and the arrays containing your mapping from the abbreviations to the full names. Use different variables. I suspect there is something wonky going on with binding these variables to a prepared statement as strings and then trying to use them as an array.

Comment: I changed all `$position` and `$team` variables with the mapping to `$position_show` and `$team_show` respectively, and the code displaying them to `$position_show[$position_full]` and `$team_show[$team_full]` respectively and it works fine now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The prepared statement is irrelevant, it's just that they were initially assigned as strings, and then you tried to use them as arrays. Another thing I suggest: assign $position_show and $team_show outside the for-loop, since they're the same all the time. Also, do it in one assignment: `$position_show = array('qb'=>'Quarterback', 'rb'=>'Running Back', ...);`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to your code at http://snipt.org/vCV8

try adding this statement before line # 97

```
$position = array();
```

and add this statement before line # 116

```
$team = array();
```